# Clone does not count toward length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  a problem with `clone()`.

```
<div id="container">
  <p id="template">a</p>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#template').clone(true, true).appendTo('#container');
    console.log($('#container').length); // it return 1, it supposed to return 2 right?, original and the cloned one.
  });
</script>
```

The length of the container after the clone is 1, why not 2?

I checked via:

```
console.log($('#container').eq(1));
```

It returns undefined.

Shouldn't the cloned element become index number 1?

Comment: id cannot be repeated in html document, use classes instead to get the desired result

Comment: use `console.log($('#container').children().length)` instead

Comment: Your example was giving a syntax error. I fixed it for you, though the edit still needs to be accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are counting the number of element `#container` what you should count is the number of element inside of the container.

Appending in `jquery` means putting an element inside the `#container`.

> calculate children's of container

```
console.log($('#container').children(".watever-class").length);
```

Comment: your welcome .. just edit one thing .. replace `watever-class` with `.watever-class`   I am unable to do that

Answer (score 1):

`$('#container')` is looking at the div called container. Since you're only looking at one div, the length of `$('#container')` is 1.

If you only want to count the number of paragraph elements inside the container, you can use this:

```
console.log($('#container p').length);
```

If you want to count the number of elements (not just paragraphs), you can use the children() function:

```
console.log($('#container').children().length);
```

Here's a JSFiddle that shows the different options and has comments explaining the three lines of code: https://jsfiddle.net/0uzusuwz/